# Unresolved resource dependencies [BasicAWSApiGateway] in the Outputs block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam-cli

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app

model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  readOrdersFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      FunctionName: readOrders
      CodeUri: read_order/
      Handler: read_orders.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        ReadOrdersApi:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref BasicAWSApiGateway
            Path: /read
            Method: get
  

    BasicAWSApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: Basic AWS Api Gateway
      StageName: Staging
      

Outputs:
  
    
  BasicAWSApiGateway:
    Description: 'API Gateway endpoint URL for Staging stage for Hello World function'
    Value: !Sub 'https://${BasicAWSApiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Staging/read/'
  BasicAWSApiGatewayRestApiId:
    Description: 'API Gateway ARN for Basic AWS API Gateway'
    Value: !Ref BasicAWSApiGateway
    Export:
      Name: BasicAWSApiGateway-RestApiId
  BasicAWSApiGatewayRootResourceId:
    Value: !GetAtt BasicAWSApiGateway.RootResourceId
    Export:
      Name: BasicAWSApiGateway-RootResourceId
```

Answer (score 1):

Indentation/whitespace is significant in YAML. `BasicAWSApiGateway` is indented too far